# Restoring Realm DB with BackupAgentHelper

Tags: android, backup, realm

I'm trying to backup and restore my realm db with BackupAgentHelper.

My problem is, when i restore the db, my app loads an empty db. I don't know exactly where the problem is, either restoring the file or my app is creating the default.realm and overwriting the restored file.

Here is my sample BackupAgent.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    FileBackupHelper hosts = new FileBackupHelper(this, Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration().getRealmFileName());
    addHelper(Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration().getRealmFileName(), hosts);
}

@Override
public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data,
                     ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    // Hold the lock while the FileBackupHelper performs backup
    synchronized (MainActivity.sDataLock) {
        Log.w("Backup", "onBackup");
        super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
    }
}

@Override
public File getFilesDir() {
    File path = getDatabasePath(Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration().getRealmFileName());
    return path.getParentFile();
}

@Override
public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode,
                      ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    Log.w("Backup", "onRestore");
    // Hold the lock while the FileBackupHelper restores the file
    synchronized (MainActivity.sDataLock) {
        Log.w("Backup", "Restoring data...");
        super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
    }
}
```

And my Application class to configure realm:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder(this)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .schemaVersion(10)
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    Log.d("Files", "MyApplication");
    logFiles();
}
```

What i found is that MyApplication class is called before the backupAgent, could that create the dbfile and the backupagent does not overwrites it?

Thanks

Comment: I am not that familiar with how the BackupAgentHelper works, but if you call `Realm.getInstance()` it will create a new empty `default.realm` file if one doesn't exists. So it does sound like the BackupAgentHelper doesn't override it.

Comment: @nacho_zona3 It is important that all instances are closed when you do the back up. Copying a memory mapped file isn't well-defined (similar to the fact that `mmap()` and network file system - NFS, CIFS - don't play well together).

Comment: @geisshirt i understand that. I'm trying to do it on my splash screen, so i didn't instantiate any realm yet. But still getting the error: It's not allowed to delete the file associated with an open Realm. Remember to close() all the instances of the Realm before deleting its file: /data/data/<package>/files/default.realm –

Comment: If you are getting that error it means that you opened the Realm somewhere.

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2552

Comment: @geisshirt that's my thread :) thanks